# Can "normal" achievements still be completed with a seasonal character?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

With the new seasons in Diablo III, I've started a new seasonal hero, haveing all achievements available for unlocking again.

But I didn't complete all the old achievements yet, so if I kill special enemies for the "Kill al these named enemies" achievements and didn't have them pre seasons yet, does my seasonal kill also count for the normal achievements? Same goes for the "drink from a stupid amount of healing fountains" and enviromental kills,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you achieve something in season mode, you also get the normal mode equivalent achievement.

Just like the example you gave in comments: if you touch 70 healing fountians with a seasonal character while you still needed 50 for the normal achievement, you'll get said achievement both in season and normal modes.

Also, from [the wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Seasons):

> **Will achievements earned in season mode also be rolled over to non-season and granted there (if you didnt previously have them in non-season)?**
>   Under current design, if you unlock an achievement on a Seasonal hero that you haven't already unlocked on a non-Seasonal hero, you'll gain credit for both at the same time.

Comment: I think you'll even get it when you touch 50 fountains on a seasonal character.  I see progress being tracked on both season/permanent.

Comment: Yep, most likely.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the season, any achievements you earn which were not earned in non season will be awarded

> Your heroes keep all their gear, crafting materials, gold, blood shards, Paragon experience, and any new recipes they may have earned during the course of a Season. This also includes any new Stash tabs purchased or Artisan levels earned (if higher than your non-Seasonal profile). Finally, if you've managed to earn achievements during a Season that you've never conquered before, you'll earn them in the corresponding non-Seasonal mode.

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/15198713/

Comment: So does that mean that if I touch 70 healing fountians with a seasonal character and I still needed 50 for the normal achievement that I'll get said achievement once the season is over?

Comment: @Arperum - Well, in theory *any* progress made should roll over. However, I cannot find anything detailing that partial achievement completion will be added when that happens. The next time I have the game open I will talk to some people who played in the ptr seasons and ask them if they noticed or not.

Comment: @Arperum Actually for that specific achievement there doesn't seem to be a season specific version of it. I completed the last 60 or so on a seasonal character, having done 440-odd on my regular ones and got the achievement. Both seasonal and non-seasonal characters seem to contribute towards it.

Comment: That should be pretty easy to verify. Just progress a little on a season achievement, switch back to non season character, and look to see if it was changed.

Comment: @Arperum you'll even get it right away.  At least that's how it worked for me this afternoon: when you achieve something in season mode, you also get the normal mode equivalent achievement.

Comment: @Anto post that as an answer yourself. I've noticed yesterday that I indeed got a normal achievement too when I got it in the season. I still wanted to check the health fountain one some more before I made an answer myself though (I kind of keep forgetting how many I had, so I don't know if the number increased or not).